# Multiple app in http.conf and assertion error

Tags: python, django, apache

i'm working with python/Django web app and after my last project i had to setup my apache http.conf to handle two app at the same time.

Both apps run as intenteded when alone in the httpd.conf, but when i put them both in the file i start having issues with asertion error.

httpd.conf part with app :

```
<VirtualHost 200.1.2.11:8080>
    ServerName 200.1.2.11:8080
    WSGIScriptAlias / "E:/Applications/var/www/YYY/YYY/wsgi.py"
    Alias /static/ "E:/Applications/var/www/YYY/static/"
    Alias /templates/ "E:/Applications/var/www/YYY/templates/"
    <Directory "E:/Applications/var/www/YYY/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory "E:/Applications/var/www/YYY/YYY">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
       </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 200.1.2.11:8081>
    ServerName 200.1.2.11:8081
    WSGIScriptAlias / "E:/Applications/var/www/XXX/XXX/wsgi.py"
    Alias /static/ "E:/Applications/var/www/XXX/static/"
    Alias /templates/ "E:/Applications/var/www/XXX/templates/"
    <Directory "E:/Applications/var/www/XXX/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory "E:/Applications/var/www/XXX/Axereal_Gestion_Mouvement">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
       </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

WSGIPythonPath E:/Applications/var/www/YYY;E:/Applications/var/www/XXX;
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Python27"
```

For example if i make a change on App A and restart apache, the A app will work but if i try to use the B app, i'm getting assertion error.

Edit : after some more research i found the bug come from me trying to run two app on the same wsgi process, from what i gather i need to use wsgi in daemon mode so that each app has a wsgi process but i can't find a way to make it work on windows.

This is my edited httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost 200.1.2.11:8080>
        WSGIDaemonProcess DjangoSite1 display-name=%{GROUP}
        WSGIProcessGroup DjangoSite1

        ServerName 200.1.2.11:8080
        WSGIScriptAlias / "E:/Applications/var/www/YYY/YYY/wsgi.py"
        Alias /static/ "E:/Applications/var/www/YYY/static/"
        Alias /templates/ "E:/Applications/var/www/YYY/templates/"
        <Directory "E:/Applications/var/www/YYY/static">
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory "E:/Applications/var/www/YYY/YYY">
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
           </Files>
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost 200.1.2.11:8081>
        WSGIDaemonProcess DjangoSite2 display-name=%{GROUP}
        WSGIProcessGroup DjangoSite2

        ServerName 200.1.2.11:8081
        WSGIScriptAlias / "E:/Applications/var/www/XXX/XXX/wsgi.py"
        Alias /static/ "E:/Applications/var/www/XXX/static/"
        Alias /templates/ "E:/Applications/var/www/XXX/templates/"
        <Directory "E:/Applications/var/www/XXX/static">
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory "E:/Applications/var/www/XXX/Axereal_Gestion_Mouvement">
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
           </Files>
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    WSGIPythonPath E:/Applications/var/www/YYY;E:/Applications/var/www/XXX;
    WSGIPythonHome "C:/Python27"
```

Problem is with this config, i get this error :

```
Invalid command 'WSGIDaemonProcess', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Edit2 :

I just found out that WSGIDaemonProcess / WSGIProcessGroup isn't aviable for windows, trying to look for something that can work on windows if anyone has managed that and could explain it would be great.

Comment: keep them both in separate files like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: @Gahan i don't see what you mean, he only setup one project and use on file in the link you gave me.

Comment: just like that you should follow same methodology for two project, means you need to create two files in for your two project instead of using single one

Comment: I understand the need for two different files, what i don't understand is how you get apache to run them both at the same time after, doesn't apache only use one conf at a time ?